# RegEx find substrings in group

Tags: substring

I try to find (select) all characters / in Group2 (red)...

(http://.*?)(/.*/)(.*?.svg?)
[image]

https://regex101.com/r/woniEN/5

How to do this?

Regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

Just use that as regex

```
(\/.*\/)
```

and then what it returns 
for each remove fir `/`

Comment: @Igor, what you mean ? 

write something about what is the expectation as output !

Comment: I need to separate symbol „/“and replace it later with „\“ for links in lots of .svg files. I hope I have now managed to explain.